# how to run selenium automation suite (smoke.xml) on different env i.e (qa/dev/stage) with docker.cmpose.yaml file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

how to run smkoe suite on different application environments (qa/dev/stage) while using docker-cmpose.yml file,

Right now i'm able to run it on one env which i'm passing through testng env variable(qa/dev/stage) and based on the given variable execution is happening on environment. Is there any way to setup same thing in docker-compose.yml

**my docker-copose.yml :**

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
    environment:
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=10
#      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=300
#      - GRID_TIMEOUT=300   

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub 
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=10
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=10
    
  smoke-suite:
    image:smoke-testing:latest
    depends_on:
      - chrome
    environment:
      - BROWSER=chrome
      - RUNTYPE=remote
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SUITE=smoke.xml
    volumes:
      - /tmp/shared/output/smoke-results:/usr/run/auto-test/test-output
```

**TesNg file :**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="10"
    preserve-order="true">

    <parameter name="suite" value="smoke" />
    <parameter name="environment" value="PP" />`
```

**Suite identification from jenkins pipline**
[image]